RgoogleMaps Создание карт в R
Я хочу создать карту в R без использования ключа API для google maps.
Мне нужна карта, на которой будут только дороги без надписей и маркеров.
MyMap <- GetMap(center=c(lat=56.852680, lon=53.206892), zoom=14,
maptype="roadmap",path="")
Всё, что я пишу в path не работает.
